# ViewPagerIndicator: Multi-line text for Tab Title?

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

I am trying to get the tab text to display in 2 lines using the in ViewPagerIndicator using the "Sample Styled Tabs" example. Here's what I have done so far:

- In [`SampleTabsStyled.java`](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/sample/src/com/viewpagerindicator/sample/SampleTabsStyled.java), I made the following change to `GoogleMusicAdapter`. Notice the new line character I added to the title string:

  ```
  @Override
  public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length].toUpperCase());
      sb.append("\n");
      sb.append(RANDOM.nextInt(1000));
      return sb.toString();
  }
  ```
- In [`styles.xml`](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/sample/res/values/styles.xml), I made the following change:

  ```
  <style name="CustomTabPageIndicator.Text" parent="android:TextAppearance.Medium">
      <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
      <item name="android:singleLine">false</item>
  </style>
  ```

However, I only see the first line of text in the VPI tabs. I don't see the second line of numbers. What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer with help on G+. Here's what I had to do:

- Don't bother with modifying the style for `CustomTabPageIndicator.Text`. I reverted it to the original.
- Add the following line to the style for `CustomTabPageIndicator`:

  ```
  <item name="android:maxLines">2</item>
  ```

That did it for me.